# Who you are. Vs Who are you

Tags: grammar, terminology

What is the grammar term for the statements / questions with question words in them?

Like:

> - I don't know who you are.
> - Do I know where **are you**?

Or:

> - Do I know where **you are**?

I don't remember the rules of these sentences, and now I wanna google the term name but don't know it either.

In the first sentence, it's not in a question form but it's a statement with question words in it!

Comment: It is not completely clear what is being asked here. Try Googling the word "interrogative"  and see what you get. Then return and rewrite this question.

Comment: Your sentences are examples of _reported questions_. There are plenty of posts about them on this site, as well as many other websites with examples and explanations

Comment: Interrogative is not what I'm looking for. But the reported speech with question words is true Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

They are called [**reported questions with question words**](https://englishgrammarexercise.com/reported-questions-english/).

> If there is a question with a question word in Direct Speech, (what, where, why, who, when, how) use this question word in Reported Speech. Again there is no auxiliary verb and the word order is like an affirmative sentence
>
> - Peter: “What time did the train leave?”
> - Peter asked me what time the train had left.

Answer (score -2):

> **wh-question** noun
>   (grammar)
>   a question that begins with ‘who’, ‘where’, ‘when’, ‘what’, ‘why’, or with ‘how’

Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 9th edition © Oxford University Press, 2015